# How can I run the same function multiple times and output different JSON data to different names?

Tags: arrays, json, arduino

I'm building a LED matrix stock ticker with ESP32 - to receive the data this function runs for the amount of selected stocks (y), it prints JSON data consecutively and then waits for 10 seconds.

What im struggling to do is store the data, each time it runs id like it to store the data as
jsonx, the x reflects which stock in the array. I can then stringify this data to scroll on the matrix screen.
From this id like to have 3 JSONVar files:
json0
json1
json2

```
void apiget(void * parameter) {
  while(true){
        for (x; x <= (y-1); x++)  {
        if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
        //HTTPClient http;
        http.begin("https://finnhub.io/api/v1/quote?symbol="+stockdef[x]+"&token=APIKEY");
               
        int httpCode = http.GET();
         if(httpCode > 0) {             
            String payload = http.getString();
            JSONVar json[x] = JSON.parse(payload);
            Serial.println(json[x]);  
          }           
          }  
          http.end();
          }
      
        x = 0;
        delay(10000);//this is required to avoid cpu watchdog for idle housekeeping
    }
    
}
```

I'm very new to programming, this has been written & copied through research and headaches lol.

I've tried using json[x] as the name in hopes it would replace the variable x and output
json0
json1
json2
but hasn't worked and i cant find any examples to copy from.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The finnhub.io API return an json object

```
{
  "c": 261.74,
  "h": 263.31,
  "l": 260.68,
  "o": 261.07,
  "pc": 259.45,
  "t": 1582641000 
}
```

I assumed that you are using the [Arduino_JSON](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Arduino_JSON) library, where `JSON.parse(payload)` return a json object type `JSONVar`. You can access each of element of the JSON object by referring to the "key" of each element.

```
if(httpCode > 0) {             
  String payload = http.getString();
  JSONVar jsonObj = JSON.parse(payload);
  float c = jsonObj["c"]; // 261.74
  float h = jsonObj["h"]; // 263.31
  float l = jsonObj["l"]; // 260.68
  float o = jsonObj["o"]; // 261.07
  float pc = jsonObj["pc"]; // 259.45
  long t = jsonOb["t"]; // 1582641000 
}
```

When you using a library, always check out the examples that come from the library. The usage that I used can be found from the library [example](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Arduino_JSON/blob/master/examples/JSONObject/JSONObject.ino) once you understand the example code.